# Tutorial that teaches simple to complex mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I've used sql server previously, and want to master mysql.

Is there a tutorial that goes into more of the advanced type queries?  It would be great if it was starting from simple and then made its way to teaching advanced queries and query optimizations etc.

If there is a book then please mention that.

thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "advanced type queries". Be more specific.

Comment: @DaveMorris What do you mean by **Advanced** ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a list of common queries, this might help:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1272

Comment: Now it says >> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/artfulso/includes/mysqlqry2i.php on line 92

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at O'Reilly's [SQL Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009762). I own a copy of this and has been pretty handy.

Comment: Its just a beginner level guide in my openion!

Answer (score -1):

this site was really really helpful when I was learning

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/